# For Loop 2nd Iteration not working in batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I am facing a issue while renaming & zipping the multiple files present inside a folder using `FOR` loop in batch.
Its 1st iteration is working fine and its renaming the file as required but when it comes to 2nd iteration it doesn't rename the file and proceeds ahead.

I am using the below code:

```
set logfile=C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\Logs\DataLoad_log.txt
echo Data Load started %date% %time% >> %logfile%
cd C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Data
for %%g in (*.csv) do (
    echo Process started for %%g >> %logfile%
    ren %%g DataloadFile.csv
    echo "zipping the Data File" >> %logfile%
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\CCM\tools\7za.exe" a C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Data\DataloadFile.zip C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Data\DataloadFile.csv
    echo "zipped the Data File" >> %logfile%
    echo -- Moving files to Backup folder - %time% >> %logfile%
    cd C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Data
    del DataloadFile.zip
    ren DataloadFile.csv %%g
    move C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Data\%%g C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Archive
    echo -- Renaming files with current date - %time% >> %logfile%
    C:
    cd C:\Oracle\"EPM Automate"\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Archive
    ren %%g %date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%%g
    echo Data load ended successfully %date% %time% >> %logfile%
)
```

In fact `%%g` is picking the 2nd file name and its getting printed in log file also. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anchit

Comment: renaming all `.csv` files to the very same name? How should that work? (besides you are missing a `)` to close the loop)

Comment: It will also attempt to rename `Dataloadfile.csv`.

Comment: Hello - Your point is valid. Actually i am renaming it to DataloadFile.csv then doing some process and renaming it back to original name and moving it to archive folder. So in short in 2nd iteration DataloadFile.csv would not be present

Comment: you should use `ren "%%~g" DataloadFile.csv` in case there are spaces in the filename(s). Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error message. And the problem is that in 1st iteration its working properly. Filenames are: LD_LEDGER_KK_DOA.csv, LD_LEDGER_KK_IEDC.csv,LD_LEDGER_KK_MPH.csv

Comment: Assuming your claims are correct, I see nothing which would prevent it from running. Please share the whole loop, so we have enough context to replicate.

Comment: Sure Sir... how can i share the file? I mean can i attach it somewhere? or just copy paste here? Please don't mind asking this, i have joined here today only.

Comment: @Anchit: the right way is to edit new information into the question (there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51769823/edit) button). I did it - please verify it's correct - I had to guess where the line breaks were.

Comment: My apologies for that. I have edited a bit. 1) There is a space in "EPM Automate". 2) Zip command is getting displayed in 3 lines here and similarly move command in 2 lines here.

Comment: Look at all your change directory commands.  Write that down to see which directory you are in each time a new file is being processed.

Comment: And for the sake of argument this is the proper way to quote file paths: `"C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\IndianaAutomation\PS_Source_Archive"`

Comment: Thankyou very much @Squashman. You are correct after the complete of 1st iteration i was in PS_Source_Archive folder so i added the cd command to get back into PS_Source_Data folder which resolved the issue. Thanks a lot. Please let me know if i have to mark the question as Closed or answered.